# MariaDB 10.2 "Mysql Row size too large”, solution for existing large DB (terabytes)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to I want to upgrade a db from Maria10.1, to Maria10.2, when I run a migration I get the 'Mysql Row size too large' error when creating some tables.

One table that is throwing this error has 40 fields defined as:

```
varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
```

The table itself is:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I think I understand the core issue; innodb will try to store varchar fields with a size < 255 ‘inline’, if a table has many columns like this it results in a row size that is too large to fit within a single database page and so the 'row size' error occurs, the error does not occur when creating this table on Maria10.1.

I have 2 solutions that I have found to work:

1. Change column definition to a type (or size) that will be stored ‘off page’ TEXT, BLOB, or VARCHAR size > 255, this allows each column to be stored within the row as a 20 byte reference rather than storing the column entirely within the row.
2. Set innodb_page_size=64k

This is fine for new databases, however I have existing databases that need to be upgraded as they run on MariaDB 10.1 which is no longer supported. These existing databases are big and applying these solutions would be difficult; for solution 2 backing up and importing terabytes of data is ’risky’ and not easy, for solution 1 there is possibly performance to consider; maybe slower queries and increased disk space requirements?

My questions:

- Firstly; is there an alternative solution that can be used for large established databases tat will provide an easier upgrade path?
- Secondly; I may have to go with solution 1, if I do how can I mitigate the performance/storage impact/will there be a significant performance/storage impact?

Some other relevant information:

[edit] I am aware of normalization but due to the amount of data this isn't really an option.

All tables are innodb

turning off innodb_strict_mode is not an option

Many thanks for looking!

Comment: Contrary to appearances, solution 1 may be more optimal.

If you are using `varchar`, the line is marked as` variable-length`. So, if you are using `TINYTEXT`, the allowance is identical to `varchar(<= 255)`.

If you have fixed-length rows, the table search is faster because the engine knows that if it moves a multiple of the row's length, it will always hit the same spot. (Or at least it was like that in the days of MyISAM)

Comment: InnoDB in MariaDB claims to support rows up to 64KiB in length. It is possible to convert a table from MyISAM to InnoDB while preserving the table's `ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT` characteristic. But the [dynamic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html#innodb-row-format-dynamic) row format is more capable.  Try doing `ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` and see if you get a workable table. You might also consider the compressed row format. This is a comment because I'm not sure it's the right answer.

Comment: And, with that many text columns in each row, you might want to investigate database normalization, splittling the text columns out into their own table. Especially if many of those columns are empty in any given row.

Comment: @O.Jones but the tables are already innodb (I've now added this to my post), and ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC does not fix it

Comment: How are the varchars defined and which character set do you use. Does the error happen in the 10.1 version? and what do you want to update? do you know that? : "Prior to MariaDB 10.2.26, MariaDB 10.3.17, and MariaDB 10.4.7, MariaDB doesn't properly calculate the row sizes while executing DDL. In these versions, unsafe tables can be created, even if InnoDB strict mode is enabled The calculations were fixed by MDEV-19292 in MariaDB 10.2.26, MariaDB 10.3.17, and MariaDB 10.4.7. "

Comment: @BerndBuffen thank you, I've added further info to the question

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question -- both before and after the upgrade.

Comment: Is 10.2 still supported?

Comment: @RickJames 10.2 may not still be supported, but this would just mean I need to upgrade to a newer version I dont think it affects the question.

Comment: MariaDb 10.2 uses InnoDb's older *Antelope* storage format, which has some limitations. Suggest you migrate to 10.3 or higher. It has *Barracuda*. Migrating data is hard enough that it's wise to migrate to the highest available version. That way it will be longer until you have to migrate again.

Comment: The storage format is Barracuda, thank you I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

> forty fields defined as varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL

So `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(col1)), ...`  for some of the likely columns.

Then devise a single `ALTER` that shrinks a few of the smallest columns to a smaller max and change any that are close to 250 to into `TEXT`.

Also, take note of whether the upgrade changed the `CHARACTER SET` away from latin1.

And note whether any of the columns you are about to change to TEXT are in any indexes.  If so, let's discuss them in more detail.

(The `ALTER` will take a long time, but probably not as long as adding compression and certainly not as long as changing page size.)

MariaDB 10.3 introduced "Storage-engine Independent Column Compression", which may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error on MySQL 5.7.34 (I don't use MariaDB).

I was able to resolve the error by changing the table to `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` and changing the columns to data type `TEXT` instead of VARCHAR. Both changes are needed. Compressed row format with varchar columns results in the same error about row size.

You probably already know this, but you can't change the InnoDB page size for just one table. To change the page size, you would have to dump all your tables (or temporarily alter them to MyISAM or another storage engine), then shut down mysqld, remove the InnoDB tablespaces and logs, change the page size option, then restart mysqld. It will initialize new InnoDB tablespaces and logs with the new page size on startup. Then you can alter your tables back to InnoDB. Obviously, this interrupts service for a long time.

Alternatives might be to set up another server instance with the greater page size, and store just this single table in it.

But I agree with the comment above from O.Jones — you should reconsider your table design that stores 40 long string columns in the same row. That kind of design is usually the result of improper normalization.

Comment: Hi @bill-karwin thanks for replying, however I am aware that changing the column type to TEXT will solve the issue, ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED is not necessary, so you haven't really provided an answer, the comment about an additional server is interesting though, thank you

Comment: @greebstreebling When I tested, I found that converting the column to data type TEXT was not sufficient. I had to do that _and_ change the row_format. Both changes were required.